# Fetching data from model with backbone posts wierd parameters

Tags: backbone.js

I have created a model and collection like this:

```
var TestModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function () {
    },
    defaults: {
        'id': null,
        'title': '',
        'description': ''
    }
});

TestCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: TestModel,
    url: function () {
        return 'Test/GetAll';
    },
});
```

I then have a view I try to load like this:

```
    var testCollection = new TestCollection();
    var testListView = new TestListView({ collection: testCollection });
    testCollection.fetch();
```

But it creates a request like:
`Test/GetAll?_=1349272902901` which fails. Do any of you know why it appends this id-like parameter to the request?

Comment: Define 'fails'. The request seems to be created correctly (`_` part was added to prevent caching, I suppose), perhaps its definition that was incorrect at first place?

Comment: Problem is not with Backbone, but with your API. If you visit the url exactly as described, what does it return? like @raina77ow mentioned, the parameter is added to prevent caching and should not effect your response. If you visit Test/GetAll and Test/GetAll?_=1349272902901, you should still get the same response from your API/server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
testCollection.fetch({ cache: false });
```

Comment: That was a valid answer, but unfortunately it didn't make any difference for me.

Comment: What happens if you go to the link Test/GetAll in browser?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I am using a ASP.NET MVC controller to provide the data and I forgot to add JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet, which prevented access. I was just misleaded by the parameter. Thanks.